# What does it mean when Google Search Console URL inspection says resources don't load due to "other error"?

Tags: google-search-console, error, resources, url-inspection-tool

I'm currently analysing some landing pages with the URL inspection tool of the Search Console, and most of them look to be not loaded (script and css). The main reason announced by Search Console is: other error (without any more information).

I was thinking the problem might be that the scripts are too complex, but some of them are very simple.